# What are the ways to connect Azure Cloud Services(Worker Roles in specific) to an on-premise database(SQL Server)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

Can you also provide some kind of comparison? I am looking to transfer lots of data.

Some ways that I can come up with:-
1) WCF service covering the on-premise DB and the cloud service connects to this using service bus
2) a point to site VNET connection b/w DB and VM on which the cloud service resides
3) On-prem DB ---(Hybrid Connection/BizService)---> AzureWebApp ----(Storage Queues)---> Azure Cloud Service   (as BizService Hybrid Connection is not available for cloud services).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the Azure App Service, MSDN will help you:

[web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server/)

[app-service-changes-existing-services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-changes-existing-services/)

Comment: Have to have a Cloud Service at one end. Business Logic's in that form.